# Submodules and direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

This question looks silly but I got little bit confused. Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $A, B, C$ and $D$ be the $R$-modules. Let $A \bigoplus B = C \bigoplus D,$ where all $A, B, C$ and $D$ cannot be expressed as a direct sum of $R$-modules. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $R$-module embedding into $C$ and $D$ respectively. Is that will be enough to say $A = C$ and $B = D$? I am little bit worried about here $A$ and $B$ are not the submodules of $C$ and $D$ respectively but identify as $R$-submodules by embedding.

Comment: Probably pedantic request for clarification:  Do you really mean (set) equality $A \oplus B = C \oplus D$ or merely isomorphism ("\cong"), $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$?

Comment: Hi Eric Towers, here is set equality.

Comment: If you meant congruence, then I'd recommend reading up on Schanuel's lemma.  (I'm dredging this up from old memories, so I can't recall enough detail to make this into an answer.  It may just be wrong-headed.)

Comment: Thank you Eric Towers. I will look.